# Django's GeoJSON serializer not serializing all fields?

Tags: python, django, geojson

I'm using Django 1.8, with GeoDjango and PostGIS. I am using `HttpResponse` to return some GeoJSON:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
code = request.GET.get('q', '')
results = PCT.objects.filter(Q(code__startswith=code) |
                                 Q(name__icontains=code))
results = results.filter(org_type='CCG')
for result in results:
    print result.code
geo_field = 'boundary'
fields = ('name', 'code', 'ons_code', 'org_type', 'boundary', )
return HttpResponse(serialize('geojson', results,
                    geometry_field=geo_field, fields=fields),
                    content_type='application/json')
```

In the console this prints a `code` field just fine:

```
99N
```

But the GeoJSON returned does not have a `properties.code` field. It has a `properties.name`, `properties.org_type` and `properties.ons_code` field though.

[image]

Why is this? Is `code` a reserved name perhaps? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: May be 'code' doesn't exist when it's None or has no value , I see the printed value on console '99N' appears once , does results list have only one object ? Can we see the whole response ?

Comment: I believe this is *because* ``code`` is not a valid part or proeprty of the [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects) specification and is not valid to put into a Feature object in serialized form. ``django-geojson`` is doing the *right* thing here AFAIK.

Comment: @Richard: I've done my best to answer your question and will happily refine the answer if it didn't help.  Can you please show what your model is and the output from serializing the object with no filters was?

Comment: @Richard Is your 'code' attribute a ForeignKey?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GeoDjango serialize GeoJSON skipping 'id' field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556679/geodjango-serialize-geojson-skipping-id-field)

Comment: Actually, I'd argue it was the other way around given that this was raised 6 months earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a quick look at the GeoJSON spec and it would appear that it only goes so far as to say that the properties field is a JSON object in its own right, so I think you're in the letter of the current specification if you want it in that part of the JSON dump.  That said, this spec is still in draft form and so subject to change (and may yet place extra constraints on this field).  Assuming that you can live with that, we can continue...

The code that handles this is in the [geojson](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/serializers/geojson.py) serializer.  This currently will only create data for the geometry, type and properties fields in `get_dump_object()`.  But you'll note that the properties field renders whatever is in `self._current`.  That field is actually built up (by the parent classes' methods) as the serializer iterates over the rest of the fields in the object.

By the time `get_dump_object()` is called, self._current should contain all the other *serializable* fields in the object.  As you can see in the [base](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/base.py) serializer class, fields will only be serialized if they are constructed with `serialize=True` and the field is in the list of specified fields you passed in to `serialize()` (or you didn't specify a filter so you're going to get everything).  I would therefore guess that your `code` field has been declared as not serializable, or it has an unexpected internal name that doesn't match your filter.

To try to fix it, I would have a look at your declaration of the `code` field in your Model for a bad serialize parameter, then just try serializing without any field list at all.  Hopefully one of those gets your missing field into the JSON.