# GeoDjango serialize GeoJSON skipping 'id' field

Tags: django, serialization, geojson, geodjango

I've been using the Geo-Django [GeoJSON serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/#geojson-serializer) so that I can retrieve some objects from a PostGIS database and display them on an OpenLayers map.

I'm obtaining the objects for display in the following way:

```
gqs = self.model.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, long(dist)))
type(gqs)
<class 'django.contrib.gis.db.models.query.GeoQuerySet'>
```

and the Geo-Objects include all the model fields as expected:

```
self.model._meta.get_fields()
(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: name>, 
<django.db.models.fields.SlugField: name_slug>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: contact>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: address>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: postcode>, 
<django.db.models.fields.EmailField: email>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: fax>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: tel>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: tel1>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: tel_fax>, 
<django.db.models.fields.URLField: url>, 
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: wardlabel>, 
<django.db.models.fields.DecimalField: lon>, 
<django.db.models.fields.DecimalField: lat>, 
<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: easting>, 
<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: northing>, 
<django.db.models.fields.DateField: first_entered>, 
<django.db.models.fields.DateField: updated>, 
<django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.PointField: point>)
```

Including the id value...

```
(Pdb) gqs[0].id
5
```

I then pass the GeoQuerySet to the GeoJSON serializer in the simplest possible way:

```
gqs_serialized = serialize('geojson', gqs)
```

and get output:

```
gqs_serialized
u'{"type": "FeatureCollection", 
  "crs": {
    "type": "name", 
    "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, 
    "features": [
    {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-0.19038, 51.490657]}, "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": {
      "tel1": null, 
      "fax": null, 
      "tel": null, 
      "name": "some club", 
      "url": null, 
      "wardlabel": "Redcliffe", 
      "lon": "-0.190380", 
      "updated": null, 
      "first_entered": "2013-12-01", 
      "contact": "some name", 
      "name_slug": "some club slug", 
      "postcode": "SW5 0JE", 
      "easting": 525732, 
      "address": "Some Address, London", 
      "lat": "51.490657", 
      "tel_fax": null, 
      "email": null, 
      "northing": 178409}},
     {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-0.137183, 51.495597]}, "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": { etc...
```

Everything is present but the 'id' field (AutoField) from the model. I want to use the id values as div id values in a webpage and I don't really want to have to create another unique id (ie. combining lon/lat values) when I think one should already be available.

What happened to the missing 'id' field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the output must be compatible with the [specs](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html), the stock serializer omits unsupported fields. However, you could craft your own serializer:

```
# yourapp/geojson_serializer.py
from django.contrib.gis.serializers import Serializer as GeoJSONSerializer

class Serializer(GeoJSONSerializer):
    def get_dump_object(self, obj):
        data = super(Serializer, self).get_dump_object(obj)
        # Extend to your taste
        data.update(id=obj.pk)
        return data
```

Enable your new serializer in `settings.py`:

```
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
        "custom_geojson": "yourapp.geojson_serializer",
}
```

And then use it in your code:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('custom_geojson', some_model)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, a neat and concise explanation. That said I clearly don't understand it fully as I haven't been able to implement it yet. As a quick fix I used the [django-geojson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-geojson) module which serializes GeoJSON that includes the id field. If you could give me an example how GeoJSONWithIdsSerializer should be called I'd appreciate it. Also I don't think Serializer exists anymore(?) I could only use: `from django.core.serializers import serialize as GeoJSONSerializer`

Comment: Managed to get this to work by changing the import statement again: 
`from django.core import serializers
GeoJSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("geojson")`
and by instantiating it as:
`gqs_serialized = GeoJSONWithIdsSerializer().serialize(gqs)`

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297594/django-serialization-error) also helped.

Comment: @jayuu, sorry for the mess, i've expanded the answer.

Comment: No problem at all. I had put the custom class in my views.py file but this is much cleaner and I expect more Pythonic too! Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this as well by using the input from [@jayuu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008684/jayuu) . For new readers 
interested in this issue I post the complete solution:

```
#myapp/geojson_serializer.py
from django.core import serializers

GeoJSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("geojson")

class Serializer(GeoJSONSerializer):
    def get_dump_object(self, obj):
        data = super(Serializer, self).get_dump_object(obj)
        # Extend to your taste
        data.update(id=obj.pk)
        return data
```

Then, to use it in my views I just imported the function because I had no interest in registering my serializer

```
#myapp/views.py
from .geojson_serializer import Serializer

def MapDataView(request):
    geojson_serializer = Serializer()
    geojson_serializer.serialize(some_queryset)
    data = geojson_serializer.getvalue()
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='json')
```

And there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

One way I solved this was asking it to serialize the "pk" field, which worked as expected.

```
gqs_serialized = serialize('geojson', gqs, fields=('pk', ))
```